# Как в SQL запросе сделать увеличение значения на 1?

Tags: sql

Есть 4 поля. Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4.

| Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

Структуры таблицы нет. Скорее всего там есть еще поля.
Необходимо вставить два значения Field2, Field3(4,name1, 1) и (4,name2, 2), так чтобы поле Field4 было уникальным, то есть увеличивалось само на 1. Как это можно реализовать? Если `Field4` не автоинкрементное?

| Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | name1 | 1 |  |
| 4 | name2 | 2 |  |

Пока сделал так, но что делать с последним полем не могу понять, может какие-то встроенные переменные

```
INSERT INTO table1( 
VALUES(4, ‘name1’, 1), (4, ‘name2’, 2)
```

Comment: А база данных какая? У оракла есть sequence, которые можно в вашем случае использовать

Comment: @gil9red, Здесь нет указаний на БД, требуется сделать наиболее общий способ подходящий под многие СУБД.
И при том, я так понимаю sequence, необходимо создавать заранее, отдельным запросом, перед использованием, а здесь же должно все ограничиваться `INSERT`

Comment: *чтобы поле Field4 было уникальным, то есть увеличивалось само на 1* Вообще-то это две разные задачи.

Comment: @Akina, извиняюсь, а почему разные?

Comment: Ну, например потому, что инкремент - далеко не единственный способ обеспечения уникальности.

Comment: @Akina, Согласен, просто, если мыслить наоборот, то инкремент - это же способ обеспечения уникальности?)
просто я выразился некорректно.

Comment: По большому счёту и это неверно. Сам инкремент ничего не гарантирует. Вот внешний независимый генератор с инкрементом внутри - да.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможное решение - преобразование массива данных в набор строк и его нумерация.

Схематично:

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( SELECT 4 Field1, ‘name1’ Field2, 1 Field3
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 4, ‘name2’, 2 ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () Field4
          FROM cte1 )
INSERT INTO table1 (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4)
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4
FROM cte2;
```

либо

```sql
WITH
cte1 AS ( SELECT 4 Field1, ‘name1’ Field2, 1 Field3
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 4, ‘name2’, 2 ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, F4 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER () Field4
          FROM cte1 
          CROSS JOIN ( SELECT MAX(Field4) F4
                       FROM table1 ) t1 )
INSERT INTO table1 (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4)
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4
FROM cte2;
```

А конкретная реализация такой схемы - это уже зависит от того, какая СУБД и какой версии.

---

PS. Задание более чем неопределённое, возможны и иные его прочтения, с иным паттерном решения. Например, это может быть генерация нумерации в триггере, или иные подходы.

Comment: Спасибо, Благодарю Вас